# get selected value(s) from checkbox group within repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

How can I get the selected value  from a checkbox group control within a repeat control in SSJS?

I want to check the selected value when the checkbox group is clicked.

The selectable value is something like:"|" + obj.unid

Comment: Some sample code would clarify the question.

Comment: Sample code where you are now! What are you repeating over. Where should the checkbox go etc

Answer (score 1):

Same pattern as every time: Don’t try to read a value from a control. Always use data binding and read the value from the binding. 
For controls in a repeat an Array or a Map will do the trick. Data binding removes the dependency on control type or name. A request scope or view scope variable should do.

Comment: does this work for a control in a repeat control? how should the data-binding look like? and the looking for removing and adding items? just now I go via getComponent("xxx").value and the id for each control in the repeat is adapted to it's unique id.

Comment: As I said: Don’t go after controls. Use data binding. That’s what it is for. You could do viewScope.repdata = {}; then you add a value for each repElement repdata[ele] = someValue; and in your repeat bind to repdata[ele]. Ele would be your repeat value